# New to c++; Entering and displaying name in C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm very new to c++, I can enter a name, but it doesn't display correctly. My tutor told me to research strings, and when I did none of it made any sense.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
char name;
printf("Hello stranger, what is your name?\n");
scanf("%c\n", &name);
system("PAUSE");
printf("\n\nWelcome to the Town of Falls Creek, %c\n",name);
}
```

Comment: This is (old) C. Use `std::string`, `std::cout`, and `std::cin`. All of these are usually discussed within the first few chapters of a C++ book.

Comment: Where are you learning C++? It's a very outdated and inaccurate source.

Comment: `My tutor told me to research strings, and when I did none of it made any sense.` Sorry, you should study it more.

Comment: Looks like C to me (-_-)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, we use `std::string` for sequences of characters. And we use `std::cout` and `std::cin` instead of printf and scanf

Be sure to look at this on internet, you will find a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
char name;
scanf("%c\n", &name);
```

is a C-style approach to read a single character from standard input.

What you should do is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
...

std::string name;
if (std::cin >> name)
    std::cout << "Hello " << name << "." << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You used a char as the variable for the name.

```
char name;
```

This is where you need to uses string.

Btw: You code would look more like modern c++ 
if you would use std::cin instead of scanf.

Answer (score 0):

char can take only single character like 'a', 'b' etc... So use string data type there.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt show you the total name because you are using char.

Instead of char use string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
std::string name;
printf("Hello stranger, what is your name?\n");
scanf("%s\n", &name);
getch();
printf("\n\nWelcome to the Town of Falls Creek, %s\n",name);
}
```

Enjoy coding!

Comment: You didn't test or even try to compile this did you? You can't read a `std::string` that way with `scanf()`.